# Passing a syscall to a function using a function pointer in C

Tags: c

I've been messing around a bit with an assignment for a class where we had to time syscall's. I had to time `read()`, `getpid()`, and `open()` called over and over. Easy stuff, but I ended up using 3 different functions. One for each syscall and each with its own for loop. I want to get it down to one. Seeing 3 functions with 3 similar for loops bothers me. I know I can make it one!

So my thought is to make a timing function that can be used for each syscall. I spent a good while reading up on making function pointers, but the issue I'm having is that `read`, `getpid`, and `open` all take different arguments (in the open and read case a specific file destination).

My question is this: Is there a way in C to make a pointer that I can pass to a function for the 3 different system calls? The extra challenge is that I cannot just call `getpid`. I found out that the system the professor is compiling caches the id so I have to use `syscall(39)` rather than `getpid()`.

Comment: You could use libffi and create a closure (where you save the syscall-specific parameters as part of the instance data), but honestly as long as it doesn't need to be able to cover a wider universe of syscalls that is a heavy solution. In the limited case you describe I would likely stick with the simple implementation.

Comment: Write wrapper functions for the syscalls (taking no arguments), pass pointers to those?

Comment: The wrapper idea is what I think I'll try. It seems to work fine so far, BUT the question I have about that approach is how much overhead does it add to the system calls? I know it might be negligible, but does it add up for testing if the system call is made a million times? Thanks for the reply's btw. And Sorone, you're totally right I should just stick with the easy implementation.